# Rect contains(x,y) doesn't trigger

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, contains, rect

I'm trying to simulate a button click in a custom android view. I need to use the `Rect.contains()` method for that, but no matter where I click on the rect it is never triggered and doesn't return true.

```
 rect = new Rect(0, 0, 720, 205);
```

An example of click coordinates is (401,103), this returns false.

```
if(rect.contains((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY())){
                    Log.w("CLICKED","");
                }
```

"CLICKED" is never logged. I've read the docs and it says 
 'left <= x < right and top <= y < bottom' to return true

in this example 0<=401<720 and 0<=103<205 which is true but doesnt seem to work.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is the Event set on screen or any other View..?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but its set in the onTouchEvent method in a custom view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getX() and getY() returns the coordinate relative to the view that dispatches the event. If that view's origin is not at 0, 0 then the it may not satisfy the `rect.contains((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY())` condition.

However, you can use getRawX() and getRawY() which returns the absolute coordinate, relative to the Screen.

**This might be the case-**

[image: pic1.png]